# Apache/PHP unable to execute convert even when called with an absolute path

Tags: php, xampp, imagemagick, executable, osx-yosemite

I have run into a truly strange issue for which i have no explanation whatsoever.

After setting up OS X Yosemite and my local dev environment using XAMPP, i installed ImageMagick through MacPorts. All is well, it runs perfectly fine on the commandline.

However, when executed through Apache and called through PHP, i get no output from it whatsoever.

I have done extensive research and found a variety of approaches:

- Setting the path environment variable in Apache (which i tried)
- Using an absolute path to the executable (which i do)
- Checking if `exec()` is listed as a disabled function (which it is not)
- Checking if `convert` is even callable, as in executable (which it is)

I even went as far as copying the `convert` executable to the local project root directory and trying to `exec('./convert');` but to no avail. I always receive absolutely no output from that call. Not even an error message. Needless to say, when i run the same thing through the Terminal, it works fine.

I also tried:

- Calling `exec('ls');` to see if anything comes up at all (yes it does, that works fine)
- Calling `exec('which convert');`, where i get no result at all - the call returns nothing
- Calling `exec('which ls');` to double-check if the problem was with `which` -  but which ls works fine and gives me `/bin/ls` as a response.
- Providing `chmod 0777` to the executable - to no avail

Regardless from what i try or do, `convert` remains entirely untouchable to PHP/Apache.

Can anyone tell me why that is and how to remedy it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the Apache error logs, i found the following message:

`dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/convert
  Reason: Incompatible library version: convert requires version 18.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 15.0.0`

Research showed that there is a common approach changing some environment path variable that applies to Apache and its subsidiary processes while running. However, since i did not want to fiddle around like that, i went for a somewhat more raw approach:

I opened a terminal and went to the very root directory of my system. There i ran:

```
find . -name "libfreetype.6.dylib"
```

This gave me all the `libfreetype.6.dylib` files that were available on my system. One of them was in the **XAMPP** `lib` directory, another one was in `/usr/local/lib`.

I backup up the file in the **XAMPP** directory and then copied the one from `/usr/local/lib` there.

I then tested `convert` again through Apache and was given another, quite similar error message relating to `libexpat.1.dylib`. For that i repeated the copying process as above. Afterwards, `convert` was executable through Apache and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

<s>When you run scripts and programs via your web server, they are being run by a different user. In Macs this is usually `_www`. The `convert` application can't be found because the path to its executable file (probably `/usr/local/bin`) isn't included in the `$PATH` environment setting for this user.</s>

<s>The simplest solution is just to prefix the command with the path to `convert`, i.e., `exec('/usr/local/bin/convert ... ');`</s>

Comment: Thank you, but if you read my question thoroughly, you will find that i have tried this, to no avail.

Comment: @SquareCat Sorry, missed that. Perhaps you are being restricted by PHP then. Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your PHP file. Check the Apache error log too.

Comment: I don't know how i could miss on checking those logs. Of course that was where i found the solution. It should be noted that it was your suggestion that got me to the right track. Thank you!